# Is this function differentiable at x=1?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

I have tried to prove differentiability using two different formulas but the results are different. Which is the correct way?
$$\begin{array}{l}
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
5 x-4 ; & 0<x \leqslant 1\\
4 x^{2}-3 x ; & x>1
\end{array}\right\}\\
\text{Test differentiability at} x=1
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
L f^{\prime}(x) &=\lim\limits_{h\to 1^{-}} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} \\
&=\lim\limits_{h\to 1^{-}} \frac{5(1+h)-4-5+4}{h} \\
&=5\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
R f^{\prime}(x) &=\lim\limits_{h\to 1^{+}} f(1+h)-f(1)\\
&=\frac{4 h^{2}-5 h}{h}\\
&=-1\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{array}{l}
\therefore\quad L f^{\prime}(x)\neq R f^{\prime}(x)\\
\therefore\quad\text{ Not Differentiable}
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{l}\lim\limits_{x\to1^{-}}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}\\
=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}\frac{5 x-5}{x-1}\\
=\lim\limits_{x\to1^{-}} \frac{5(x-1)}{(x-1)}=5\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{l}\lim\limits_{x\to 1+} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} \\
=\lim\limits_{x\to1^{+}} \frac{4 x^{2}-3 x-1}{x-1}\\
=\lim\limits_{x\to1+}\frac{(4 x+1)(x-1)}{(x-1)}\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{l}
\therefore\quad L f^{\prime}(x)=R f^{\prime}(x) \\
\therefore\text{ differentiable.}\end{array}$$

Comment: Never post unsearchable pictures.  Take the time to typeset (in *MathJax*).

Comment: Hello,could you click on the description?

Comment: Your Right hand limit calculations make no sense.  How do you get $f(1+h) - f(1) = 4h^2 -5h$?  Don't understand at all.  Unless you were calculating it in your head.. In which case... don't.  $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac {f(1+h)-f(1)}h=\lim \frac {4(1+2h+h^2)-3(1+h)- (5(1)-4)}h=\lim \frac {4+8h+4h^2-3-3h-1}h=\lim\frac {5h+4h^2}h=\lim 5+4h = 5$.  It's a match

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the first definitions is wrong. The correct one is
$$f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
which is equivalent to
$$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\,.$$